# Continuing FILTER Formula to Another Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I use the "FILTER" formula. The data drawn by the formula does not fit in the whole line. How can I get the continuation of the data it captured in the next column? It should be like in the picture. It should continue on the other column. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can append your columns using [vertical column combination formulas](https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/combine-columns-in-google-sheets/).

### Sample Formula:

```
=Filter({B4:D8;F4:H8},NOT(ISBLANK(B4:B13)))
```

### Output:

[image]

- I combined range B4:D8 and F4:H8 and check if column B is not blank as filter condition. Notice that the condition I used was B4:B13, this is because when we append F4:H8, it will give you 13 as the end row (8 + 5 = 13)

Comment: Hi. The "limit" and "offset" functions in the "query" formula worked for me. Thanks anyway.